# How can I replace MariaDB with MySQL in XAMPP (Mac version)

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, xampp, mariadb

My problem is not with the MariaDB, i have found that there's no problem in using it instead of MySQL.

PS : I'm using XAMPP for OS X the latest version.

The problem appeared when I did this :
in localhost/phpmyadmin : I have created a new database in order to import my huge database in it, to do so I need to use the Terminal (OS X), so I need to access to the mysql command line interface, I have found that this is the path I need to use :

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
```

But when I access to that path, I found that I'm not in a MySQL command line but in MariaDB command line (and I have no problem in that) but when I run show databases; it doesn't show me the empty database I have created earlier using phpMyAdmin

My question is : I need to use one of those two DB techs, only one of them, I need to see the same technology in both phpMyAdmin and in the Terminal

Comment: Summarizing your first sentence: "My problem is not with the MariaDB, i have found that there's no problem in using it instead of MySQL.". Could you please explain why you like to move to MySQL if there is no problem with MariaDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When logged in as one user, you cannot see another user's databases.

Either fix the `GRANTs` or connect as a `SUPER` user.